# Trouble connecting to azure db from server 2012R2

Tags: vb.net, azure, windows-server-2012-r2

We are migrating all our sites from MS Server 2008 to Server 2012R2. The issue is with a particular site. there are certain pages that use a connection string to an azure db from our client to access their data. We migrated this site a couple of weeks ago of which there were no issues. Now errors were being throw on these pages.  The error is:

`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)`

There were updates our hosting provider made, and presumed that was the case. However, when the updates were rolled back the issue still persists.  I added a staging site on the old server, with the exact same code and had no issues with connecting to the azure db. Either, there was some change on the new server or some change on our clients end. Here is the code im using:

```
        Dim sAzureDB As String = "Server=tcp:<address>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<DBNAME>;User ID=<USERNAME>;Password=<PASSWORD>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"

        Public Function GetDistinctDivisionGroup(Optional ByVal OGroupID As Integer = -1) As DataSet

            OpenConn("<Stored Procedure>", CommandType.StoredProcedure, sAzureDB)

            Dim oAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim oData As New DataSet
            oAdapter.SelectCommand = oCmd

            oCmd.Parameters.Clear()

            If OGroupID > -1 Then
                oCmd.Parameters.Add("@OGroupID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = OGroupID
            End If

            Try

                oAdapter.Fill(oData, "DistinctDivision")

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            Finally
                KillConn()
            End Try

            Return oData
        End Function

        Private oConn As SqlConnection
        Private oCmd As SqlCommand


        Private Sub OpenConn(ByVal ThisCommandText As String, ByVal ThisCommandType As CommandType, Optional ByVal AlternateConnection As String = "", Optional ByVal UseRDB As Boolean = False)

            If UseRDB Then
                oConn = New SqlConnection(HttpContext.Current.Application("conString"))
            Else
                If AlternateConnection <> "" Then
                    oConn = New SqlConnection(AlternateConnection)
                Else
                    oConn = New SqlConnection(HttpContext.Current.Application("conRString"))
                End If
            End If

            oCmd = New SqlCommand()

            ' wait 60 seconds before timing out
            oCmd.CommandTimeout = 60

            oCmd.Connection = oConn

            ' the content is being edited
            oCmd.CommandText = ThisCommandText
            oCmd.CommandType = ThisCommandType

            ' now open the connection
            oConn.Open()

        End Sub

        Private Sub KillConn()
            RF.ConjunctionJunction.CleanUpTime(oCmd, oConn)
        End Sub
```

Here's other code in another vb file which disposes of the connection :

```
            Namespace RF

                Public Class ConjunctionJunction        
                    ''' <summary>
                    ''' Closes the connection and disposes of the command object passed in.
                    ''' </summary>
                    ''' <param name="CommandObject">The command object to clean up</param>
                    ''' <remarks></remarks>
                    Shared Sub CleanUpTime(ByVal CommandObject As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, _
                            ByVal ConnectionObject As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)

                        ' kill the connection
                        ConnectionObject.Close()
                        ConnectionObject.Dispose()
                        ConnectionObject = Nothing

                        ' kill the command
                        CommandObject.Dispose()
                        CommandObject = Nothing

                    End Sub

                End Class


            End Namespace
```

Why would it be the code above would work on Server 2008 but not on server 2012R2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling TLS 1.0 on your Server 2012R2 box?

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/29/protecting-against-the-ssl-3-0-vulnerability/